# How to solve slow loading page containing database information

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mysql

On one page that contains links to the database on my website, the page loads very slowly, is there any way to speed up the loading of that page?
I tried it on the server and when there were no visitors just import database and it immediately slowed down loading the page. 
You can inspect the page via my website: https://translatesubtitles.com/browse_subtitle.php or check the page code: 
I think it may be up to the database table to slow it down, you can look at the table code below:

```
    <div class="row">
        <table id="example" data-order='[[ 0, "desc" ]]' class="table table-striped " style="width:100%">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="display: none">ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Language</th>
                <th>Author</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>


            <?php
            include("my.php");
            $query = "SELECT * FROM me order by id DESC";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="display: none"><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
                        <td><a href="your.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></a></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['language']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['author']; ?></td>
                    </tr>

                <?php }} ?>

            </tbody>

        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: You website looks like you are loading 14k rows and putting them into pages. Recommend fetching a page as required. Techniques on how to do this are [here](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination).

Answer (score 2):

Have you already added `id` as an index to the table? If not, adding one should help.

```
ALTER TABLE `me` ADD INDEX `id` (`id`)
```

You might also be able to cut down on the amount of data that's transferred by selecting only the columns that you need. E.g.

```
SELECT id, name, language, author FROM me ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: Note if `id` is the primary key the added index is not required. Limiting output fields could be still useful.